# Update image in SQL using FileUpload in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I'm trying to store profile images for users in SQL. My problem is that nothing  is saved in the database table. The column where I want to save the image has `image` as datatype.

Here is my code:

UPDATE: Code updated and working. The problem was the parameters used in the query. Many thanks to SeM and Crowcoder!

```
protected void ButtonPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contenttype = string.Empty;
        string username = User.Identity.Name; // Gets the current username

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".jpg":
                contenttype = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contenttype = "image/png";
                break;
        }

        if (contenttype != string.Empty)
        {
            Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length + 1);

            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0,   bytes.Length);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string strQuery = "UPDATE Users SET Image=@data WHERE Username=@user";

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", bytes)); 
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", username));
                        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "Filformat stöds inte." +
              " Endast jpg/png är tillåtet";
        }
    }
```

The conversion to a byte array is working but I can't figure out where the problem could be.

Comment: put try/catch block and figure out the the error

Comment: The project has an xml configuration file where the connection string is located.  Open xml and check if connection string is correct ("LoginDBConnectionString").

Comment: Where did you use `SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter()`?

Comment: Is there a row in the table for the username for which you are uploading an image?

Comment: Can you run Sql Profiler to see what query is hitting the database?

Comment: may be this is because you are saving **bytes** values to **image** datatype.Go through this [link](http://asp.net-informations.com/dbpro/files/asp-image-database-default.aspx.cs.htm) may help you out.

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Users SET Image=@data WHERE Username=@user',N'@data image,@user nvarchar(35)',@data=default,@user=N'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName'  -  Found this in profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter()){}`, then change that part like this:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", bytes));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", LoginName1.ToString()));
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Handle your exception   
}
```

catch your exception and check problems from database or query string.

Comment: the query has already been assigned at using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery))

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, then I forgot to delete it from answer.

Comment: @SeM, you are right to suggest removal of `SqlDataAdapter` but that would not be the cause of any problems.

Comment: Yes, but by adding it on try catch block and properly handling exception will give the probably cause of problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be that (cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bytes;) gives data a default value which results in NULL in sql database. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What error gives you this: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Image));`?

Comment: @SeM, you are not assigning any value to the parameters in your answer.

Comment: @Crowcoder oops, sorry, I didn't notice that, my bad. UPDATED!

Comment: @AndréS. Use this: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", bytes));`

Comment: @SeM Thank you! That fix plus 'User.Identity.Name' to fetch username fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch block to know the exception you get.

Remove the sql data adapter since you didn't use it.

Try referring this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/uploading-images-to-database-using-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/).

Answer (score 0):

> exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Users SET Image=@data WHERE Username=@user',N'@data image,@user nvarchar(35)',@data=default,@user=N'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName' - Found this in profiler

Assuming `LoginName1` is a `TextBox`, you must access the `Text` property to get the value. If you `ToString()` a control you get what you are seeing, the name of the control: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginName`

You must do:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", LoginName1.Text));
```

> UPDATE:

I should have noticed that LoginName1 is not a TextBox. You may have to access the `User` property, I don't see a property on `LoginName` control to get the value but maybe I'm just missing it.